# How do I allow users to choose where to upload the file?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I allow users to chose where to upload the file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11379813/how-do-i-allow-users-to-chose-where-to-upload-the-file)

I want to allow my users to chose where to upload their files. If anyone could help me, that'd be great.

uploader.html
http://pastebin.com/LQP9jxLH

```
<div id="main">
<center><h2>File Uploader Beta</h2></center><br />
<center>
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
File: <input type="file" name="filename" />
<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
</center>
</div>
```

upload.php
http://pastebin.com/CtM1LW13

```
$folder = "files/";
$HTTP_POST_FILES = "";
if(isset($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])) // Check if $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'] is there
{
        if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']))  {  
                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], $folder.$_FILES['filename']['name'])) {
                        Echo "Your file has been uploaded! You should probably tell Cody what you uploaded so he can get it in the right place. :)";
                } else {
                        Echo "Haha! You don't have access to do that.";
        }
        } else {
                Echo "Your upload has failed.";
        }
}
```

All help is appreciated. :)

Also, I need it to generate a script into the page once the file has uploaded.
Say, if example.jpg was uploaded to /Cody/Pictures.
It would delete

## No files were found..

and replace it with:
File Name: $FileName
Download:

Can anyone do that? Thanks if you can!

Comment: two things: 1. format your code
2. try to not mix HTML and PHP!
try to post only post the parts, which are interesting for the question... omg! and don't use the font-tag...come on, this is so yesterday!

Comment: Where are you stuck? What have you tried? We won't write the code for you.

Comment: 1 You aren't helpful. 2. You are supposed to mix it!

Comment: You're not exactly asking a question here, you're just asking for someone to do it for you. This site is about helping with specific problems, not a free labor site. However you should liik at the `$folder` variable for changing the upload destination and `session_start()` should come before any other PHP or HTML

Comment: I am honestly stuck everywhere. I have tried a few things.

Comment: https://www.google.at/search?sourceid=chrome&client=ubuntu&channel=cs&ie=UTF-8&q=php+html+upload+a+file+tutorial

Comment: I guess he specified his top level folder in `$folder`, so that should not be the problem, the problem is rather a good filter disallowing `\..` in order to prevent hackers to move to upper level directories, and of course disallowing .php extensions for all uploads because.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only do this because you seem to be so young:

I would add a field containing the upload path called `path` (as its name attribute) into your upload form, the upload path can simply be typed in or chosen using a folder selector: You could iterate through the top level of your upload directory (`$folder`) using the PHP-function `scandir` (`$files=scandir($folder);`). This delivers a list of all files and folders in `$folder`. (Let's assume, it contains the folder `foo` and the file `index.html`). At this point you iterate the list (`$files`) delivered by the `scandir`-function and check if the current item is a directory using `is_dir`.

```
function listFiles($directory)
{
    $files=scandir($directory);
    for($i=0; $i < count($files); $i++)
    {
        if(is_dir($files[$i]) && file_exists($files[$i]))
        {
            echo '<a href="javascript:getFolderContents('.json_encode($files[$i]).');">'.htmlentities($files[$i]).'</a>';
        }
    }
}
echo '<div id="uploadcontainer">';
listFiles($folder); //you must have declared $folder
echo '</div>';
```

If so, you can generate a dynamic hyperlink, which executes a dynamic JavaScript function. For the top level of you would receive exactly one link like:

```
<a href="javascript:getFolderContents('foo');">foo</a>`
```

Of course you need to define the function getFolderContents which is a JavaScript function that delivers the folder contents of its parameter using JSON or Ajax.

```
function getFolderContents(folder)
{
    Request=new XMLHttpRequest();
    Request.open("GET", "/getFolderContents.php?folder="+encodeURIComponent(folder), true);
    Request.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if(Request.readyState==4 && Request.status==200) //succeeded
        {
            document.getElementsByName("path")[0].value=folder+"/";
            document.getElementById("uploadcontainer").innerHTML=Request.responseText;
        }
    }
    Request.send(null);
}
```

As this request is sent to `/getFolderContents.php` you need to create this PHP-file and simply copy the function `listFiles` (as you can see above) in there and just execute the following code:

```
listFiles($_GET["folder"]);
```

I haven't tested it, only quickly written and of course you have adapt it to your needs. And there are still some options missing like, moving one directory up again or so, because this script won't allow you to get back.

Best regards from Germany.

Comment: Don't have enough rep for vote up.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the form - for example

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
File: <input type="file" name="filename" /><br />
Directory: <select name="folder">
<option>Bob</option>
<option>Cody</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

And the upload.php file

Change the line: $folder = "files/";

```
$folder = $_POST[folder]."/";
```

Make sure you have created the directories Bob and Cody.

That should get you started.

Try to look into styling with CSS

```
<style>
.someclass{
  color:#FFF;
  font-weight:700;
}
</style>

<div class="someclass">White bold text</div>
<div class="someclass">Also White bold text</div>
```

I know you're only 13 so stick with it :)

Comment: Thanks! I will try. I am getting a head start on college!